# React-native-document-picker not working in android

Tags: react-native

React-native-document-picker not working in android 
after selecting image app stopped.

react-native ver:-59.5
react-native-document-picker --v:-3.2.4

I am using this code.

````
    var results = await DocumentPicker.pickMultiple({
      type: [DocumentPicker.types.images],
    });
    for(var res of results) {
     this.setState({
      getSecondFile:res,
      chosepic_2:res.uri
    })
    console.log(
                  res.uri,
                  res.type, // mime type
                  res.name,
                  res.size
                );
   }
 } catch (err) {
  if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
    // User cancelled the picker, exit any dialogs or menus and move on
  } else {
    throw err;
  }
}```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to include the code.

Comment: Please check you log. What exist error occur please post log here

Comment: not showing any error in log,
it stoped after selecting file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project. i used another library i.e react-native-open-doc and it not work properly in my project.and i used android studio for found out the error.

you can use this code for find the file in console

`````
  try {
    const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
      type: [DocumentPicker.types. allFiles],
    });

    console.log(
      res
    );
  } catch (err) {
    if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
      // User cancelled the picker, exit any dialogs or menus and move on
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  }
}````
`````